# storage object in google bucket is not marked as deleted. once lifecycle has been set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

Im trying to work with lifecycle settings in google bucket

my folder name : 2022-08-21T08:38:30_93731. so you can see the date is from yesterday

my rule in the bucket is :

```
{"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"age": 1}}]}
```

but the folder the objects there is still available
how can i know if my lifecycle is working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [sample example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/lifecycle#examples) your json code is correct but when coming to [delete there are few exceptions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#delete). Kindly check if this might be the reason not working.

The Delete action deletes an object when the object meets all conditions specified in the lifecycle rule.

Exception:

In buckets with Object Versioning enabled, deleting the live version of an object causes it to become a noncurrent version, while deleting a noncurrent version deletes that version permanently. See the [configuration for deleting objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle-configurations#deletion-example) for an example of using the Delete action along with Object Versioning.

The Delete action does not take effect on an object while the object has an [object hold](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-holds) placed on it or a [retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock#retention-policy) that it has not yet fulfilled. As long as the conditions in the Delete action remain satisfied for the object, the Delete action occurs after any object hold is removed and any retention policy is fulfilled.

Apart from the above, you need to have grant **storage.buckets.delete**
[IAM Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-json) on the cloud storage bucket to delete.